# New MongoDB Install, single insert resulting in duplicate documents

Tags: php, macos, mongodb

I've setup MongoDB on my Mac and am using PHP to communicate with it. I've installed the PHP driver for Mongo and am successfully connecting and making inserts and selects from the DB.

The problem I'm having is that when I do an insert into Mongo, I am seeing 2 copies of the document, even though I've only called the insert function once.

Here is the php code:

```
   <?php
    $mongoDB = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongoDB->blog;
    $collection = $db->posts;
    $document = array( "title" => "cat with a hat", "body" => "once upon a time a cat with a hat ...");
    $collection->insert($document);
```

The result in the db is:

```
> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5089ff5aaa3479c97300000f"), "title" : "cat with a hat", "body" : "once upon a time a cat with a hat ..." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5089ff5aaa3479c973000011"), "title" : "cat with a hat", "body" : "once upon a time a cat with a hat ..." }
```

I'm not sure if this a problem with the PHP driver, Mongo, Apache or my OS. I used Brew to install Mongo and PECL to install the mongo driver (pecl install mongo).

Why do I get 2 copies when I insert into Mongo?

edit: fixed typo in php code. Thanks bcmcfc

Comment: Have you mis-pasted your example code? You're inserting `$document` but the data is in `$post`.

Comment: What is `$document` in your code example?

Comment: I had a typo in the code I pasted, thanks for pointing that out. Changed it above.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an upsert:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php

Comment: that should only matter if he already had a document in the collection, no?